# Is any option to move Oracle Analytics Cloud in Azure?

Tags: azure, oracle-analytics, oracle-analytics-cloud

I have an Oracle Analytics Cloud instance in Oracle Cloud.

Is there a way to move it to Azure? I understand that OAC is PaaS, so I'd say it is not a way to move it as is. But I'd appreciate a confirmation of this assumption.

Also, just wondering if switching OAC to classic instance (doing the opposite of [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/analytics-cloud/acmgp/prepare-migrate-oracle-analytics-cloud-classic-instances.html)) and then upload that VM to Azure cloud, IaaS.

Answer (score 1):

OAC only runs on Oracle Cloud. The "Classic" you mentions isn't available to buy anymore since a long time and only legacy customers are still running it.

If you want to run Oracle Analytics on Azure you'll need to go for Oracle Analytics Server.